# Создание фонового приложения C#

Tags: c#

Пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы скомпилированный .exe файл отображался в диспетчере задач, не как приложение, а как фоновый процесс. Как можно это реализовать в Visual Studio?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Создавайте службу и запускайте ее, ну или запускайте "фоново" (например, при запуске компьютера через планировщик, или еще как).

Comment: Ваш фоновый процесс - это всего лишь приложение без активных окон. Сделать можно разными способами, в зависимости от задач, решаемых приложением. Это, например, может быть полноценная служба windows, либо приложение, которое активирует свои окна по требованию, а в остальное время просто висит значком в трее.